# Javascript Cannot use .now() on date string

Tags: javascript, angular

So I wanted to compare two dates inside a post object. I tried to compare the date objects, but that returned NaN. Then I tried converting it to milliseconds since 1970 by using .now() on these dates, but it returned the following error:

```
It happens:  TypeError: a.date.now is not a function
```

I tried `typeof a.date` and this returned `string`. I don't know why I can't use the .now() method. Can someone help me?

**the whole function inside of angular service**

```
getPosts(section) {
        return this.http.get(url + '/forum/getPosts/' + section )
          .map( (posts: any) => {
            // posts should be ordened based on latest replies. If there are no replies yet, we compare it to the date
            // of the original post
            posts.obj.sort((a, b) => {
              const aHasReplies = a.replies.length !== 0;
              const bHasReplies = b.replies.length !== 0;

              if (aHasReplies && bHasReplies ) {
                return a.replies.slice(-1, 1)[0].date - b.replies.slice(-1, 1)[0].date;
              } else if ( aHasReplies && !bHasReplies) {
                return a.replies.slice(-1, 1)[0].date - b.date;
              } else if ( !aHasReplies && bHasReplies) {
                return a.date - b.replies.slice(-1, 1)[0].date;
              } else {
                console.log(a.date.now());
                return a.date - b.date;
              }
            });
            return posts;
          });
    }
```

Comment: um theres no such return for `typeof` that returns `date string` - do you mean just `string`?

Comment: Strings don't have a `now` method. You are getting JSON that is serialised as an object with string fields, so you won't get Date objects that do have a `now` method.

Comment: Shit, my bad. It returns string, not date string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be object, not string, if that's what you meant, because there is no "date string".
Other than that try:

```
new Date(a.date).getTime()
```

Because .now is a static method, you always use it as **Date.now()**

This means, that Date.now() always returns milliseconds elapsed since the UNIX epoch.
For converting to unix time use getTime.

If you want to compare them, compare two dates without conversion.

But keep in mind, that unix time is in seconds, and javascript method return in milliseconds. If you need exactly unix time, divide by 1000.

Comment: Yeah, I made a stupid mistake it returns string, not date string. I'll try your steps and get back to you

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two dates in the year-month-day format (yyyy-mm-dd) using regular javascript comparators such as < and > etc

Answer (score -3):

I suggest use `moment.js` library (https://momentjs.com/docs/) to parse Date from String.
So you can have some thing like

`let date = moment(a.date)`

Comment: I definitely would not recommend to grab such big libraries just for this purposes, just to check two dates.

Comment: @askerovlab unless you care about the dates being correct, I suppose. Because parsing date strings is notoriously unreliable in JS and varies by implementation. Your best bet is an ISO8601 or RFC2822 date format. The latter probably has the widest support but not necessarily. ISO dates work OK until they don't - older JS environments may "support" it badly or not at all. You could have the date parsed in UTC instead of local or not, which means you can have inconsistent dates between instances. You could also parse the dates manually but if you're dealing with dates, you probably want Moment.

Comment: yeah, moment.js help me prevent bug with Date when need run many kind of devices